# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name OnetoOne Mapping

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm newb to JPA. I'm having trouble with defining OneToOne bidirectional flow on my classes.

UserInfo.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserInfo")
public class UserInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idUserInfo;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;


@OneToOne(mappedBy="UserInfo")
private LoginInfo loginInfo;
```

LoginInfo.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LoginInfo")
public class LoginInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idLoginInfo;

@Column(name="emailId")
private String emailId;

//bidirectional one to one association to UserInfo
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="emailId", referencedColumnName="loginInfo")
private UserInfo userInfo;


private String sessionId;
private String password;
```

Here's sql to create those tables:

```
   CREATE TABLE `LoginInfo` (
     `emailId` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `idLoginInfo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`idLoginInfo`),
     UNIQUE KEY `emailId_UNIQUE` (`emailId`),
     UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`idLoginInfo`)
   );

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `UserInfo`;
    CREATE TABLE `UserInfo` (
      `idUserInfo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `firstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `lastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `loginInfo` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`idUserInfo`),
      UNIQUE KEY `idUserInfo_UNIQUE` (`idUserInfo`),
      UNIQUE KEY `loginInfo_UNIQUE` (`loginInfo`),
      CONSTRAINT `loginInfo` FOREIGN KEY (`loginInfo`) REFERENCES `LoginInfo` (`emailId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
      );
```

When I start the Tomcat server, I'm getting the follow exception on ContextInitialization.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: loginInfo in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(UserInfo) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

But the column do exist on the UserInfo table. Can somebody please help me if the mapping is right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading about OneToOne mapping, annotations and some trial & error, I was able to use the LoginInfo and UserInfo tables successfully. In my question above, it has some invalid mappings. The requirement was that UserInfo be the owner entity and LoginInfo as the child entity. So as suggested by ashokhein, I used PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation. This is how my tables look like now.

```
CREATE TABLE `login_info` (
  `user_info_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_info_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email_id_UNIQUE` (`email_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user_info_id_UNIQUE` (`user_info_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_login_info_user_info` FOREIGN KEY (`user_info_id`) REFERENCES `user_info`  (`user_info_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `user_info_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_info_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_info_id_UNIQUE` (`user_info_id`));
```

This is how my classes look like:

UserInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_info")
public class UserInfo {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_info_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private LoginInfo loginInfo;

//Getters and setters
```

LoginInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "login_info")
public class LoginInfo {

@Id
@Column(name = "user_info_id")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "userInfo"))
private Integer id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private UserInfo userInfo;

@Column(name = "email_id")
private String emailId;

//Getters and setters
```

And this is how I create and save the entities to the table:

```
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
userInfo.setFirstName(registerUserRequest.getFirstName());
userInfo.setLastName(registerUserRequest.getLastName());

LoginInfo loginInfo = userInfo.getLoginInfo(); 
if(loginInfo == null) {
    loginInfo = new LoginInfo();
}
loginInfo.setEmailId(registerUserRequest.getEmailId());
loginInfo.setUserInfo(userInfo);
userInfo.setLoginInfo(loginInfo);

if(userService.create(userInfo)) {
    logger.debug("User created successfully");
} else {
    throw new UserAlreadyExistException();
}
```

During the course of getting to this solution, I encountered bunch of hibernate exceptions and issues. Here's some(if it helps someone)

```
Error: identifier of an instance of  was altered from 14 to 14
```

Solution: The primary key on the Entity classes where different types initially. The column user_info_id was declared as Integer in UserInfo and long in LoginInfo.

```
Error: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property
```

Solution: While creating the UserInfo object, I did "userInfo.setLoginInfo(loginInfo)" but did not set "loginInfo.setUserInfo(userInfo)". After fixing that, it was fine.

```
Note: If you see a better way to do the same, please do comment here and let me know. Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 2):

Invalid association : **@JoinColumn(name="emailId", referencedColumnName="loginInfo")**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserInfo")
public class UserInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idUserInfo;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private LoginInfo loginInfo;


@Entity
@Table(name="LoginInfo")
public class LoginInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idLoginInfo;

@Column(name="emailId")
private String emailId;

//bidirectional one to one association to UserInfo
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  
private UserInfo userInfo;


private String sessionId;
private String password;
```